# Java Spring Won't Fetch Incoming Relationship for Neo4j Database

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, relationship

I am using `Spring Data Neo4j (SDN) v4.1.3`. and I have problem when having two entities which have relationship.
Chair and Class (we assume this class have constructor and setter & getter):

```
@NodeEntity
public class Chair {
  @GraphId
  private Long graphId;

  private String id;

  private String name;

  @Relationship(type = "room_has_chair", direction = "INCOMING")
  private Room room;

  @Relationship(type = "chair_has_color", direction = "OUTGOING")
  private Color color;
}

@NodeEntity
public class Room {
  @GraphId
  private Long graphId;

  private String id;

  private String name;
}


@NodeEntity
public class Color {
  @GraphId
  private Long graphId;

  private String id;

  private String name;
}
```

I didn't give any Chair property at Room class because to avoid infinite loop when fetching.
We have repository too to to connect to database: ChairRepository,  RoomRepository and ColorRepository.
And how I set relationship is:

```
private ChairRepository chairRepository;
private RoomRepository roomRepository;
private ColorRepository colorRepository;

Room room = new Room();
room.setName("Room 1");
roomRepository.save(room);

Color color = new Color();
color.setName("Red");
colorRepository.save(color);

Chair chair = new Chair();
chair.setName("Chair 1");
chair.setRoom(room);
chair.setColor(color);
chairRepository.save(chair);
```

When I check the database (localhost:7474) the data is exist and correct.
"Room 1" --> "Chair 1" --> "Red"
But when I fetch the Chair (with repository findById()) I got Chair class and I can see the Color class from chair.getColor() << this is exist.
However when I looking for chair.getRoom() << this is empty.
Does anyone know what happen to my SDN?